# ¿Qué ocasiona este problema?

Tags: java, selenium, test

Estoy haciendo una automatización y al momento de hacer la verificación me sale lo siguiente:

> java.lang.AssertionError: 
>       Expected: "true"
>            but: was 
>         at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.ErrorTally.throwSummaryExceptionFrom(ErrorTally.java:36)
>         at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.ErrorTally.reportAnyErrors(ErrorTally.java:30)
>         at net.serenitybdd.screenplay.Actor.should(Actor.java:231)

Y esta es la comparación que realizo:

```
public class CompararSaldo implements Question<Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean answeredBy(Actor actor) {
        if (!strSCIFFSALDOSaldoAntes.trim().equals(strSCIFFSALDOSaldoDespues.trim())) {
            return false;

        }
            return true;
    }


    public static CompararSaldo luegoDelDesembolso() {
        return new CompararSaldo();
    }
}
```

Y aquí lo invoco

```
actor.should(seeThat(CompararSaldo.luegoDelDesembolso(), equalTo("true")));
```

¿Alguna idea de lo que pueda pasar?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que aquí le mando un String con el valor true y la comparación la hace con un tipo boolean

```
actor.should(seeThat(CompararSaldo.luegoDelDesembolso(), equalTo("true")));
```

Lo que hice fue importar todas las dependencias de hamcrest

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
```

Y ya solo hice la verificación así:

```
actor.should(seeThat(LaComparacionDelSaldo.luegoDelDesembolso(), equalTo(true)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar las funciones que provee *serenity* para hacer preguntas que no requieran modelar objecto.

```
import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.questions.WebElementQuestion.the;
```

y también para aplicar validaciones

```
import static net.serenitybdd.screenplay.matchers.WebElementStateMatchers.containsText;
```

Aca esta toda la [documentacion](https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/screenplay-selenium-tasks.html).